# How will the ceiling fan behave if I put unequal turns on different slots of same coil?

Tags: fan, split-phase

Recently I opened a ceiling fan in my home trying to understand its basic operating principle.While i was through it a few questions popped up in my mind, which are as follows:-

1.What will happen if we give different no of turns in different slots of the Running coil?

2. On what factors we decide the no of turns of running and starting coil?

As far as my speculation tells me giving different turns would create poles of different magnetic strengths that would lead to its abnormal behavior.But i dont have a clear idea of how things will proceed in such a scenerio.

Any suggestions would be much helpful.

Comment: Search schematics which use different caps to control speed.

Comment: If it has say 6 identical poles and you wind one of them with a different number of turns it will result in some small amount of oscillating torque.  As they are usually induction motors the change will be very slight as the average torque cannot tell how much each pole contributes.

Comment: okay.. but will these oscillations lead to harmonics in the system thus reducing the system performance or is some other factor also responsible for it.